# Наибольшая общая подпоследовательность

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Может кто помочь мне с задачей?? необходимо найти наибольшую общую последовательность с помощью матрицы на C#. Не рекурсивно.
Как я понял надо взять 2 массива Char, найти наибольшую общую подпоследовательность и вывести на экран консоли в виде таблицы,примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Большие проблемы с самим алгоритмом и его реализацией. Большинство информации в интернете написано на других языках или на псевдокодах которые не понятны мне. Поэтому нужна помощь

Comment: По какому принципу построена эта таблица? Что именно означает `наибольшая общая подплследовательность` в вашей задаче? Что вы конкретно сделали, чтобы решить задачу и какие результаты получили?

Comment: без понятия по какому принципу, она не моя, и я просто обрисовал что вывод должен быть структурирован, не обязательно именно таблица, но чтобы хотя бы вид был. наибольшая общая подпоследовательность означает наибольшая общая подпоследовательность)))

Comment: Если вы не знаете даже что именно вам надо сделать, то никто вам не подскажет. Как вы можете решать задачу не понимая постановки задачи? Вот если вам кто то предложит какое то решение, как вы поймете, верное оно или нет?

Comment: я прекрасно знаю что именно мне нужно сделать. может быть я поставил не верно вопрос и не понятно вам что требуется???

Comment: в таком случае я могу уточнить если не до конца понятно что требуется

Comment: мои вопросы очень простые: 1) Что конкретно должен делать алгоритм? Какие данные на входе и на выходе и почему? 2) Как вы сами пытались решить вашу задачу и что не получилось?

Comment: Что конкретно он должен делать ясно написано в самом вопрос на мой взгляд. на вход должны быть 2 слова из массива Char на выходе подобная таблица как в описании. почему? потому что именно это и требуется. "Решить задачу максимальной подпоследовательности с помощью
матрицы." Яснее уже некуда. Что сам пытался?? да все пытался что возможно, но я не такой гений чтобы изобретать велосипед и придумать свой алгоритм, или дойти до него собственной головой. Все это написано в описании.

Comment: хорошо, я поясню по другому. Есть возрастающая подпоследовательность, убывающая подпоследовательность, подпоследовательность и одинаковых элементов - какой у вас вариант? Например, если у вы ищете подпоследовательность, где порядок букв не важен, что я изначально подумал, то у вас на картинке 3 столбец выглядит неверно, так как строки "ba" и "abca" по идее содержат подпоследовательность "ba" из 2 элементов, а в таблице показана единица - потому я и спросил, что конкретно надо сделать, так как мое предположение не совпало с таблицей

Comment: У меня вариант - Наибольшая. какая из перечисленных вами не указана, да я и сам не знаю, только известно что требуется найти наибольшую.
Картинку я просто взял из интернета для примера, чтобы показать наглядно какой должен быть вывод.

Comment: Но судя по всему нужна возрастающая, и важен порядок букв

Comment: Если возрастающая, тогда я не понял, как получилось число 4 в конце таблицы.  Давайте сделаем проще, я покажу пример, а вы сами решите, подойдет он вам или нет, но результат с вашей картинкой совпадать не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если забить задачу в гугл, то в первой ссылке будет [алгоритм решения](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Если поглядеть на рекуррентное соотношение, то будет примерно понятно, как строить матрицу.

```
public void MaxSubSeq(string s1, string s2)
{
    // считаем матрицу
    var matrix = new int[s1.Length + 1, s2.Length + 1];
    for (var i = 1; i <= s1.Length; i++)    
        for (var j = 1; j <= s2.Length; j++)        
            matrix[i, j] = s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 
                         (matrix[i - 1, j - 1] + 1) : 
                         Math.Max(matrix[i - 1, j], matrix[i, j - 1]);

    // выводим матрицу в консоль
    for (var i = 0; i <= s1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <= s2.Length; j++)
            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
MaxSubSeq("abcabaac", "baccbca");
```

Вывод

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
0  1  1  1  1  2  2  2
0  1  1  2  2  2  3  3
0  1  2  2  2  2  3  4
0  1  2  2  2  3  3  4
0  1  2  2  2  3  3  4
0  1  2  2  2  3  3  4
0  1  2  3  3  3  4  4
```

**UPD**

для работы с массивами char изменения минимальны

```
public void MaxSubSeq(char[] s1, char[] s2)
{
    // считаем матрицу
    var matrix = new int[s1.Length + 1, s2.Length + 1];
    for (var i = 1; i <= s1.Length; i++)    
        for (var j = 1; j <= s2.Length; j++)        
            matrix[i, j] = s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 
                         (matrix[i - 1, j - 1] + 1) : 
                         Math.Max(matrix[i - 1, j], matrix[i, j - 1]);

    // выводим матрицу в консоль
    for (var i = 0; i <= s1.Length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <= s2.Length; j++)
            Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Вызов

```
MaxSubSeq("abcabaac".ToCharArray(), "baccbca".ToCharArray());
```

Результат аналогичный.

Comment: Да вывод правильный, но нельзя использовать строки, только массивы Char.
Можно тоже самое только с массивами Char с примером передачи их в метод и вызов самого метода с параметрами в Main??? потому что с этим тоже есть затруднения у меня. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @Venen обновил ответ

Comment: Так вот значит как... Чтож буду знать теперь.
Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Venen пожалуйста